# SharePoint REST orderby on expanded field

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, orderby

I would like to do an orderby on an expanded field when querying a SharePoint list.

so for example: `$select=File/Name&$expand=File&$orderby=File/Name`

However, including the orderby on the expanded property causes an error. I can successfully order by fields on the main level, just not at the expanded level.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 0):

Jake,

I haven't been able to order by an expanded field (yet), but if you're trying to sort by file name, you can use the following REST ODATA query:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('documents')/items/?$select=FileLeafRef&$orderby=FileLeafRef%20asc
```

`FileLeafRef` is a top-level field containing the file name.

Which I found using:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('documents')/Fields
```

to get the list of fields available on the list.

I hope it helps?

Comment: Thats actually is a good workaround! Thanks for the quick assistance Hugo!